# Losing Focus of Textbox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a silver light page in which i am entering some value in a text box (this is not the first Text box in appearance) and clicking on the search button.
After getting the result from the database the focus is losing to and shifting to the first text box which is also a search criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything?

You need to first re focus your Silverlight app, then set the focus to the text box that you want.

try:

```
this.Focus(); then Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { mytextbox.Focus();});
```

Comment: I am using MVVVM pattern can you please provide some info about that.

Comment: I dont see how using MVVM would make a difference to the code i just posted. Or do you mean general info about MVVM? if so see this for reference: [Intro to MVVM](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/anand_raja/archive/2012/02/20/the-model-view-viewmodel-101-part-1.aspx)